# React Hook Async await how to hold rendering on a promise

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-hooks

I'm trying to fetch data while using async await but i'm getting errors when i'm trying to render. i assume is because i'm trying to render when it is in it's promise state.

The end game is trying to make this an action, i want to use this with React redux. But i wanted to start here first.

// App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from "axios"

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const response = await axios(
                'http://lr.test/api/players',
            );
            console.log('data',response.data);

            setData(response.data);
            //setLoading(false) //i tried to set loading to false when it is ready but this doesn't work
            
        }

        fetchData()

    }, []);

    return (
           <ul>
                 {
                    data.map( (d) => {
                        console.log(d)
                        return (<li key={d.id}>{d}</li>)
                    })
                }
          </ul>
       )
```

//This give me error is not a function, so it's trying to render when it is a promise
//how do i get around this? I tried checcking is array before rendering but that doesn't seem to work.

My console log is

```
{} //first empty object

{data: Array(4)}
data: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of initializing `data` with an empty object

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
```

initialize it with an empty array which has the `map` function:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

This should make the initial render work.

By the way, if you are really logging `response.data` and the log shows an object containing yet another `data` property, you should use `response.data.data` instead.

Comment: thats a good point i didn't realize that, sometimes in the console log i get data Promise
will React try render when i setData() and it's passing in a Promise